# How to redirect a header file(to a library) to include some code in the instantiation?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a header file to a library(the library I can't touch).  But I need to include some more functionality in the instantiation.  How can I do this?

```
class AA: public QObject
{
    public:
        void AA(); //<-- I need to add some more functionality to this
}
```

The only way, I  know, is if it were possible to subclass AA into a new class with the same name AA, so that from the main program, the hope is to use the second one.  But I don't think this is possible.

Comment: If you can't derive your own class from AA then...you can't.

Comment: If you want to replace "in toto" the other library (let's say "library.dll") and it's small enough what you can do is to **wrap** every single class it exports (and it's used by your application, called "application.exe") inside a 3rd DLL (let's say "wrap.dll"). application.exe will have a reference to wrap.dll, wrap.dll will reference library.dll and it'll forward all calls. It's not always possible but it _may_ work in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For code that's already been compiled (that you don't have the source for), you can't intercept it without going through extraordinary means (patching memory using assembly language). This is assuming that QObject doesn't have some special mechanism that would allow you to "hook" the constructor.

For code that you have control over, you can simply subclass AA and provide your own functionality in the constructor of your subclass.